# Render Angular 2 image with postfix

Tags: image, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I got an image with postfix that set validation for image etc.
This image is served from aws. Does anyone know how to go around it?
example:

```
example_bs6fPLY.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJM45BBCD7SX6UTPA&Signature=vOHcC4pwmYjfOts1jphoaeP%2Bamo%3D&Expires=1505349454
```

Comment: Question not clear? What is your problem?

Comment: the issue I am having that I can not render the image. it give me an error.

Comment: What is the error do you get?

Comment: that's the strange thing, that i get no error, just it does not render, but I was able to go around it by cleaning up the URL